# How to convert const char* to uint16_t octal (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, octal, leading-zero

I need to convert values with leading zero to octal. Because 12 (14 octal) is different from 012 (10 octal)

The function I will call requires a variable of type uint16_t and the value to be converted is received dynamically and can be stored in a String or const char*.

`String node = "012"; // received dynamically`

`const char* node = '012'; // received dynamically`

What I need is:
`uint16_t n = node;`

The function:

`begin(uint8_t _channel, uint16_t _node_address )`

`begin(90, n);`

Comment: Can you just call `strtol` or `strtoul`?

Comment: Use `std::stoi` _"...prefix (0) indicating octal base..."_    https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: c or c++? `const char* node = '012'` is invalid in both. What is `String`? Is it an alias for `std::string`, `char *` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned strToInt(const char *str, int base)
{
    const char digits[] = "01234567890ABCDEF";
    unsigned result = 0;

    while(*str)
    {
        result *= base;
        result += strchr(digits, *str++) - digits;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Work fine for me.